# Стандартные средства для реализации Синхронизированной частично дублирующей коллекции

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, listview, коллекции

Доброго времени суток.

Есть коллекция ObservalableCollection слева(3 поля) и ObservalableCollection справа(2 поля). Объекты в таблицах одинакового класса. По сути 2-ая таблица является отфильтрованной 1-ой таблицей. Я хочу связать 2 коллекции, чтобы при удаление из одной коллекции удалялся этот же элемент из другой коллекции и наоборот.

Вопрос: есть ли стандартные средства для подобного?(я имею ввиду код, фильтры в Xaml не могу использовать, ибо TreeView) и если нет, то как использовать ID элементов коллекции в другой коллекции?(не ID класса, а ID элемента. Т.е при добавлении элемента в одну коллекцию добавлялся в другую с тем же ID).

Чтобы не пересекалось, можно при добавлении в обе коллекции смотреть на главную таблицу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пока плохо понятно, у вас нарисованы 2 таблицы с разным количеством элементов, как они между собой связаны? Тип элементов в коллекции одинаковый?

Comment: @Андрей вот их и нужно связать. 2 таблица является отфильтрованной 1 таблицей. Элементы те же самые. Тип одинаковый.  Вторая таблица должна является зависимой от первой.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обычно, для этого используются представления. Например, [`CollectionView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.data.collectionview(v=vs.110).aspx). Оберни в него свою коллекцию и установи свойство `Filter`. На изменения в `ObservableCollection` ты можешь подписаться - событие `CollectionChanged`. Так же для любого `CollectionViewSource` ты можешь задать свойство [`IsLiveFilteting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.livefilteringproperties(v=vs.110).aspx) для отслеживания изменений отдельных свойств.

Для того, чтобы обратится к отфильтрованным значениям, используйте обращение к свойству CollectionViewSource.View.

Comment: Изначально и наткнулся на этот подход, но не додумался создать его не в XAML, а в коде. Все работает как надо.